# Is there a modal operator which distributes over the implication?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Is there any notable modal operator $\Box$, so that if $P,Q$ are proposition

$$\left(\Box(P\implies Q)\right)\Leftrightarrow\left(\Box P\implies \Box Q\right)$$

Comment: Although not a "modal operator", implication left distributes over implication. Perhaps "modal" should be added to the subject line (besides appearing in the body of the Question).

Comment: @hardmath: Yeah, I can add it. I didn't want to scare off people.

Answer (score 2):

The -> direction *is* the distribution axiom of K.

Sources:
http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#ModLog

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for the Stanford reference, I'll look into that. The initial motivation for me is this [reddit question](http://www.reddit.com/r/logic/comments/28f0c6/how_do_you_translate_inverse_relationships_into/) which made me think of how to model a "switch" or "nagation" , which lets me express the correlated system in which the following holds: If P rises then Q rises, hence if P falls, then Q falls."

Comment: In your second part (□A→□B) is "assumed", and the Necessitation Rule will not apply unless (□A→□B) is a theorem of K.

Comment: thank you. Thats right. The initial post was sloppy

Comment: The system of modal logic where the conclusion of the Necessitation Rule holds unconditionally is called the Trivial Modal System.  In such case the distributive property of the Question holds.  So perhaps we should ask if that is the only consistent such logic.

Comment: See my comment below. You can have a smaller-than-Trivial system where $A$ entails $\square A$ but not the reverse, and $\diamond A$ entails $A$ but not the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a two-world model: in the actual world (say) $P$ is true and $Q$ is false. In the only other possible world $P$ is false and $Q$ is true. Assume every world is accessible from every other world (so this is an S5 model)

(i) Since $P$ is true and $Q$ is false at the actual world, $P \to Q$ is false, so isn't necessarily true, i.e. $\Box(P \to Q)$ is **false** at the actual world. [Assuming a world is accessible from itself.]

(ii) Since $P$ is false at the other world, $P$ is not necessarily true, so $\Box P$ is false at the actual world, hence $(\Box P \to \Box Q)$ is **true** there.

So that's a model that shows that $(\Box P \to \Box Q)$ does not logically entail $\Box(P \to Q)$ in S5. So it won't follow in weaker-than-S5 modal logics either, including ones where the box doesn't mean "necessary".

Comment: Okay, I have to stomach this a little. But in any case "$\Box$" in my question is just a name, right, I don't really want to indicate necessity with it.

Comment: I believe $\diamond$ should distribute for *at most reflexive* frames (worlds accessible only from themselves or not at all).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this axiom to the axioms for normal modal logic K based on classical propositional logic is equivalent (using propositional logic) to adding the normality axiom (as mentioned before) together with the two axioms $\Box Q \rightarrow \Box (\neg P \vee Q)$ and $\Box P \vee \Box (P \rightarrow Q)$. The first one follows from monotonicity of $\Box$, while the second one is the axiom $Alt_1$. This gives you the logic $KAlt_1$ of frames where every world sees at most one world (see e.g. Hughes & Cresswell, "A New Introduction to Modal Logic", 1996, p.142).